# Como expor um conjunto de funções que está dentro de um objeto no escopo global?

Tags: javascript, objetos, escopo-de-variáveis

Estou construindo uma API em JavaScript que retorna um conjunto de funções acessíveis através de um objeto.

Toda vez que quero acessar alguma destas funções, preciso enunciar o objeto, por exemplo: `minhaAPI.funcao1`, contudo não queria ter que fazer isso toda vez.

Sei que posso fazer isso:

```
const { funcao1 } = minhaAPI
```

para então poder fazer:

```
funcao1()
```

ao invés de:

```
minhaAPI.funcao1()
```

Contudo procuro um método mais automatizado, onde não seja preciso enunciar todas as funções que vou usar.

Qual seria a melhor solução para isso?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eu realmente não o aconselho a fazer isso. Primeiro porque você pode poluir o escopo global ou até mesmo sobrescrever uma propriedade original no caso de haver conflito de nome.

No entanto, se você realmente tiver uma boa razão (o que acho difícil), uma opção para fazer isso seria adicionar explicitamente todas as propriedades do dado objeto no escopo global, utilizando algo como [`globalThis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis) (que é o mesmo que `window` em *browsers* ou `global` no Node.js):

```js
const obj = {
  name: 'Foo',
  age: 123
};

Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
  // ⛔️ NÃO RECOMENDO FAZER ISSO. É UM ANTI-PATTERN
  globalThis[key] = obj[key];
});

console.log(name); // 'Foo';
console.log(age); // 123
```

Mas observe que isso **sobrescreve** (literalmente) o escopo global, o que **não é uma boa ideia**.

Poderia utilizar também o *statement* [`with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with), mas ele está obsoleto (justamente pelo fato de que estender o escopo léxico a partir de um objeto não é uma algo desejável).

Eu repensaria a necessidade disso, já que é, indubitavelmente, uma gambiarra. Nesse tipo de situação, ser explícito é bem melhor do que implícito. Não faça as coisas por "preguiça" de escrever um pouco mais de código, uma vez que declarar variáveis explicitamente será, na maioria das vezes, sempre melhor. Fora que, se você tiver utilizando TypeScript, a declaração explícita lhe traz segurança de tipos sem a necessidade de configurações adicionais.

Em suma: repense a necessidade disso. Não é tão necessário quanto você pensa (e se for, cabe editar a resposta, porque "mais automatizado" não me parece uma boa razão para procurar sobrescrever o escopo).

Comment: No Swift quando você importa um módulo as funções ficam dispostas no escopo de forma que não é necessário enunciar o módulo todas as vezes. No meu ponto de vista isso é uma abordagem mais interessante. Obrigado pela resposta!

Comment: Concordo com você que é interessante e às vezes pode acabar ajudando, mas infelizmente não temos isso no JS, aí tem que se fazer explicitamente mesmo. :/