# O que é o globalThis no JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, característica-linguagem

Estava olhando um exemplo de código e me deparei com um exemplo que tinha `globalThis`:

```js
// timeout de 1s
globalThis.setTimeout(() => alert('Olá'), 1000);
```

O `setTimeout` sem segredos, mas não tinha visto ainda esse objeto `globalThis`, apenas o `setTimeout` sozinho ou assim: `window.setTimeout`.

O que é esse objeto `globalThis`?

Comment: [Relacionado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/483396/95771), mas vale um resposta completa

Comment: humm interessante @CmteCardeal, pelo nome sugere algo como um this "global", mas ele está substituindo o `window`, pelo que vi na pergunta é algo como alias, mas "multiplataforma", seria isso?

Comment: Exato. Ele faz um _resolver_ do objeto global de acordo com a plataforma de execucao do codigo JS.

Comment: legal, posta uma resposta com isso pra documentar melhor :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Intro

O objeto global é considerado um problema que o JavaScript não consegue se livrar devido a retrocompatibilidade. Todo desenvolvedor sabe a dor de cabeça que é tentar criar/modificar/remover alguma funcionalidade do JavaScript sem quebrar nenhum código que faz o uso desta funcionalidade. Além disso, o objeto global afeta negativamente a resposta como demonstrado [nesta minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/482278/95771), pelo menos nos navegadores.

O ECMAScript implementou alguns recursos para evitarmos mais facilmente o uso não intencional do objeto *global*. `const` e `let`, por exemplo, não criam propriedades no objeto global. Além de no Node.js, cada módulo (arquivo de script) tem seu próprio escopo para evitar afetar o global do Node.js. Pense no escopo que todo o código do módulo (arquivo) está dentro de uma função.

### História

Historicamente, acessar o objeto global com JavaScript requer uma sintaxe diferente de acordo com o ambiente de execução do código JavaScript.

- Nos browsers, podemos acessar o objeto global usando `window`, `self` ou `frames`

```js
console.log(window);
console.log(self);
console.log(frames);
```

Inclusive se fizermos uma comparação, podemos ver que `window` e `frames` tem o mesmo ponteiro na memória:

```js
console.log(window === frames); // true
```

<sub>`self` só funciona no contexto de [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker).</sub>

- No Node.js, nenhuma das formas acima funciona. Você deveria usar o `global`:

```js
$ node
Welcome to Node.js v14.15.0.
Type ".help" for more information.
> console.log(global)
// imprime:
// <ref *1> Object [global] {
//   global: [Circular *1],
//   clearInterval: [Function: clearInterval],
//   clearTimeout: [Function: clearTimeout],
//   setInterval: [Function: setInterval],
//   setTimeout: [Function: setTimeout] {
//     [Symbol(nodejs.util.promisify.custom)]: [Function (anonymous)]
//   },
//   queueMicrotask: [Function: queueMicrotask],
//   clearImmediate: [Function: clearImmediate],
//   setImmediate: [Function: setImmediate] {
//     [Symbol(nodejs.util.promisify.custom)]: [Function (anonymous)]
//   }
// }
// undefined
// >
```

É possível acessar o objeto global através do `this` em uma função sem uso do `'use strict'`, mas sabemos os problemas que isso pode gerar.

```js
(function() {
  console.log(this); // => Window {...}
})();

(() => {
  console.log(this); // => Window {...}
})();

(function() {
  'use strict';
  console.log(this); // => undefined
})();
```

Antes da introdução do `globalThis`, tínhamos duas maneiras de se retornar o objeto global:

1. Uso do `Function('return this')()`:

```js
console.log(Function('return this')());
```

Mas essa forma não era a mais adequada, pois gerava problemas de [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP).

2. Uso de uma função personalizada. Vamos fazer um exemplo em que queremos saber se o `setTimeout`, por exemplo, está presente no ambiente de execução. Fazendo um `if`, temos o código:

```js
var getGlobal = function() {
  if (typeof self !== 'undefined') {
    return self;
  }
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    return window;
  }
  if (typeof global !== 'undefined') {
    return global;
  }
  throw new Error('unable to locate global object');
};

var globals = getGlobal();

if (typeof globals.setTimeout !== 'function') {
  // setTimeout não está presente nesse ambiente
}
```

Convenhamos que é muito código para se fazer uma coisa simples.

### Atualmente

Com a introdução do `globalThis`, ele fica responsável por fazer um *resolver* do contexto do ambiente de execução do código JavaScript e retornar o objeto global correspondente ao ambiente de execução. O uso das funções mencionadas em `1` e `2` já não são mais necessárias e o código ficaria bem mais simples:

```js
if (typeof globalThis.setTimeout !== 'function') {
  // setTimeout não está presente nesse ambiente
}
```

### Utilidade

Onde o uso do `globalThis` seria bem vindo:

- Detecção de recursos para descobrir quais deles um contexto de execução JavaScript suporta;
- [Polyfills](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Glossario/Polyfill) que fornecem novos recursos em mecanismos JavaScript.

> Por exemplo, um *polyfill* pode ser usado para imitar a funcionalidade de um elemento HTML Canvas no Microsoft Internet Explorer 7, usando um plugin Silverlight, ou imitar o suporte para unidades `rem` CSS ou `text-shadow`; ou o que você quiser.

- Nunca implementei este exemplo, mas funcionou. Vamos supor que você queira criar uma função `digaOla` e você quer poder usá-la em todos os ambientes que você rode código JavaScript. Você possui uma mesma aplicação adaptada para funcionar no browser, nos dispositivos móveis, no desktop, em IoT (por que não?) e a alma da aplicação está no seu servidor Node.js. Como reaproveitar a mesma função `digaOla` em todo o contexto de execução em cada plataforma? Usando o `globalThis` e não se preocupando em escrever códigos gigantescos para suportar diferentes contextos, em fazer verificações e testes.

Usando no browser:

```js
if (!globalThis.digaOla) {
  console.log('Posso criar minha função!');

  globalThis.digaOla = function () {
    return 'Olá :)';
  };
} else {
  console.log('Não posso criar minha função!');
}

console.log('Dizendo olá: ', globalThis.digaOla());
```

Como poderia ser reaproveitado e usado no Node.js:

Arquivos:

```
  |  
   \_ test.js
  |
   \_ test2.js
```

**test2.js**:

```js
module.exports = {
  test: () => {
    console.log('De dentro do arquivo test_copy.js: ', globalThis.digaOla());
  }
};
```

**test.js**:

```js
if (!globalThis.digaOla) {
  console.log('Posso criar minha função!');

  globalThis.digaOla = function () {
    return 'Olá :)';
  };
} else {
  console.log('Não posso criar minha função!');
}

console.log('Dizendo olá: ', globalThis.digaOla());

const { test } = require('./test2');

test();
```

Executando `node test.js`:

```js
$ node test.js
Posso criar minha função!
Dizendo olá:  Olá :)
Dizendo olá de dentro do arquivo test_copy.js:  Olá :)
```

---

Links:

- [ES feature: globalThis](https://2ality.com/2019/08/global-this.html)
- [Compatibilidade atual no *Can I Use*?](https://caniuse.com/?search=globalThis)

Comment: E o melhor do `globalThis` é o **_[polyfill](https://github.com/lffg2/sopt/blob/main/global-snippets/globalThis-polyfill.js)_**, que coisa linda! #sqn