# O que é e para quê serve o objeto exótico WindowProxy?

Tags: javascript, objetos

Enquanto procurava bons links para [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/495647/95771), me deparei com uma citação a um objeto chamado `WindowProxy`. Na procura por explicações, encontrei [este link](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/window-object.html#the-windowproxy-exotic-object) com a definição:

> A WindowProxy is an exotic object that wraps a Window ordinary object, indirecting most operations through to the wrapped object. Each browsing context has an associated WindowProxy object. When the browsing context is navigated, the Window object wrapped by the browsing context's associated WindowProxy object is changed.

Traduzindo:

> Um WindowProxy é um objeto exótico que envolve um objeto comum do Window, direcionando a maioria das operações para o objeto empacotado. Cada contexto de navegação tem um objeto WindowProxy associado. Quando o contexto de navegação é navegado (alterado), o objeto Window envolvido pelo objeto WindowProxy associado ao contexto de navegação é alterado.

Oque eu entendi:

> ...

Nunca tinha ouvido falar nesse objeto. Nem se quer encontrei algo relacionado aqui no SOpt.

[Neste link do MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/self), temos outra citação:

> The Window.self read-only property returns the window itself, as a WindowProxy. It can be used with dot notation on a window object (that is, window.self) or standalone (self).

Pelo pouco que entendi da definição acima, esta é uma implementação que não temos contato diretamente, ela acontece meio que "por de baixo dos panos".

Cada `window` é associado ao `windowProxy` e quando você trabalha com o `window`, não é o objeto `window` de fato, mas sim uma representação do `window` que muda a cada contexto de navegação, um `WindowProxy`. O que de certa forma, faz sentido. Por exemplo o código abaixo:

<sub>A minha afirmação acima é uma dedução. Não tenho certeza se isto está certo.</sub>

```js
function a () {
  if (!window.teste) {
    window.teste = 'Olá!'
  } else {
    console.log('window.teste já foi definido!');
  }
}

a();

console.log(window.teste);
```

Se eu recarregar a página, o `console.log('window.teste já foi definido!');` nunca vai ser executado, pois o contexto mudou e um novo `WindowProxy` foi criado, ou associado (não sei).

Estou assumindo que este objeto não tem grande utilidade, ou não tem importância para desenvolvimento em aplicações nos navegadores, e claro que não posso afirmar com certeza. Gostaria de saber ao menos um pouco sobre o assunto e se minha explicação acima está correta. Talvez alguém vai informar que não tem importância/utilidade esse `WindoProxy` e ele é só um conceito sobre contexto de execução para o `window`.

---

Falta de links, incluindo a [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLObjectElement/contentWindow) (*WindowProxy* aparece em vermelho, indicando falta de link).